# Php in cmd unable to load ALL dinamic libraries

Tags: php

When i use php in cmd Windows console i got the following error:

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25>php
>       PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_bz2.dll' - No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.
>        in Unknown on line 0
>      [...]

And continues whit ALL the dll libraries. I Chek the rute and its ok. And when my wamp start a page whit php i dont get this error

For example i got the error when i type:

```
cd C:\wamp64\www\ServicioApp\scripts
php script_notificaciones.php
```

I run php --ini and search in the file, and i got:

```
extension_dir ="c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/"
```

Comment: Is that space in `php5. 6.25` actually there, or just a victim of copy/paste? If it is, you'll need to check your cli php.ini file for rogue spaces.

Comment: Victim of copy/paste. I Fix it in original post

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that WAMP (its Apache config) looks for `php.ini` in different location than command line invoked script - run `php --ini` in console to find it. You will need to check and fix (or disable) extension paths there.

Search for line with `extension_dir` - it should point to ext folder with extensions (dlls). You may need to switch to backslashes there:

```
extension_dir = "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext"
```

Comment: I run php --ini and checks the file appeards. And got the correct route. And still failed load ALL extensions

Comment: @Efeyabel And paths to these extesions are correct?

Comment: @Efeyabel Use backslashes and delete trailing slash

Comment: I edit to this: `extension_dir ="c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\"` and still not work

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem my rute was:

```
c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/
```

And must be:

```
c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/
```

I miss the 64*